# Laravel 4 - Error uploading input file

Tags: php, file, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and I know that maybe this question is repeated but any solution worked for me. I am trying to upload a file, just that. Then I want to upload multiple files(that is because "catalogo[]"). I think the error is in the getClientOriginalName method but I am not sure. Here is my code.

```
$itemCat = new CatalogosElectromedicina;
    if (Input::hasFile('catalogo')) {
        $nombreCat = Input::file('catalogo')->getClientOriginalName();
        Input::file('catalogo')->move('catalogos/', $nombreCat);
        $itemCat->nombre = $nombreCat;
    }elseif(!Input::hasFile('catalogo')){
        $itemCat->nombre = "";
    }

    $itemCat->descripcion = Input::get('nombre_cat');
    $itemCat->save();
```

And this is my form.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    {{ Form::file('catalogo[]') }}
</div>
```

This is the error and continues (it is really long):

Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /myroottotheproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php on line 280 and defined...

In my Form::open, I already have the option 'files' => 'true' and 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'. Any help it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code.

```
$files = $request->file('catalogo[]');

if($request->hasFile('catalogo[]'))
{
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        // file upload code like this with your variable.
       $nombreCat = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       $file->move('folder/', $nombreCat);
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it. The solution was to make a foreach because it is an array. However I didn't tested it with the $request. Thank you ;)

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you, Thanks